# Replace multiple row values in a list using another list using mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to update a table that has many rows with a column called "sku".  I have a full list of existing "sku" values and I'd like to change them all to another value, which I also have as a list. I have the two lists matched in a spreadsheet where they are paired up.  Example:

Old SKU VALUE | NEW SKU VALUE

```
|'old1' | 'new1'|
|'old2' | 'new2'|
|'old3' | 'new3'|
...
```

etc...

The old and new names are of various values so I can't just replace the word 'old' with 'new' so I need to use a fully paired up set of values.

I am fine building many many rows of "replace" calls and tried something like the following but it wasn't valid syntax.

```
update tf_table
set sku = replace (sku, 'old1', 'new1'),
set sku = replace (sku, 'old2', 'new2'),
set sku = replace (sku, 'old3', 'new3');
...
```

I saw in another ticket that nesting replace calls is possible, but that would be a very deep set of nested calls since the two lists contain over 250 values each.  It doesn't have to be efficient, it is a one time thing.  Appreciate any help.

Comment: Create a table with your replace list and then just do the update using that. Like `UPDATE tf_table INNER JOIN replace_table ON tf_table.sku = replace_table.old_sku_value SET tf_table.sku = replace_table.new_sku_value;`

Comment: That's a pretty good idea, I'll try that out, thanks!

Comment: JNevill, more than a pretty good idea, worked perfectly.  Thank you so much.